# Make mushroom/fire flower blocks alternate

Tags: super-mario-maker

If you've played the original Super Mario Bros., you've probably noticed that blocks can contain a Mushroom or Fire Flower depending on if you're big or not.

However, in Super Mario Maker, putting a Mushroom into a block always gives you a Mushroom and putting a Fire Flower into a block always gives you a Fire Flower.

Is there any way to replicate the Super Mario Bros. behavior in Super Mario Maker?

Comment: Note: Super Mario Bros. 3 (most of the time) and Super Mario World did this as well, not sure about New SMB U.

Comment: When I said most of the time above, there are instances in SMB3 and SMW where it goes directly to a more powerful powerup.

Comment: I believe this seems to be the case with New SMB U as well. So far though, I don't think this was implemented in Super Mario Maker. I've been keeping the mushrooms for the beginning of my levels.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To combine a power-up with a Super Mushroom in a ?-Mark Block:

- Place a power-up somewhere in the level (for example a Fire Flower).
- Drag a Super Mushroom onto the power-up.
- Drag the combined power-ups onto a ?-Mark Block.

[Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=esX_FPaZdDQ)

Answer (score 10):

According to [this YouTube video from Nintendo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=esX_FPaZdDQ) Mario Maker will be receiving this functionality come Nov. 4th (Nov. 5th in Europe). You will be able to attach powerups together and then place them in a block. By attaching a Super Mushroom to a Fire Flower, for example, and placing it inside a block, Mario will receive the Super Mushroom when he is small and the Fire Flower when he is large.

---

The pre-update method to accomplish this was like so: When there are already two Yoshis on screen, the next egg to hatch will have a power-up that varies depending on which power Mario already has.

Small Mario -> Mushroom

Big Mario   -> Fire Flower

Fire Flower -> Mystery, Leaf, or Helicopter, depending on Game Style

You can throw together a hodge-podge power-up block by walling off a pipe that spawns Yoshi Eggs and placing a ? Block (with a Yoshi Egg inside it) next to this setup. It works better if Mario is already riding Yoshi, or you place an egg below the pipe manually, as the pipe needs only spawn one more onto the screen and there's less chance the player will just end up with another Yoshi from the ? block.